# Plugin that fires on Import of solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have written a quick plugin with the aim of logging publishes and solution imports in a Dynamics CRM 2011 solution.

The plugin is really simple, it should just listen for the SDK messages that relate to these actions and do some actions accordingly.

For Publishes it works fine; I have a pre-operation steps registered for the Publish and PublishAll messages and my plugin code is called.

For solution imports however I was under the impression that registering steps against the ImportCompressedAll, ImportCompressedWithProgress, ImportAll, Import and ImportWithProgress messages would suffice, but my plugin is never called with these registered in either Pre or Post-Operation steps.

Has anyone managed to achieve this functionality, or see why these messages are not called for solution imports?

I did find a CRM 4 post that suggests these messages would work, and as both solution imports and data imports are both stored as jobs in the same SQL table the logic seems sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this before and it was impossible on 2011 and 2013

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I found. Guess I will have to make do with a solution that polls the database

Answer (score 0):

The ImportCompressedAll, ImportCompressedWithProgress, ImportAll, Import and ImportWithProgress SDK messages fire during data import not solution import.  Thus, you're not going to get your plugin to fire if you registered for these messages and are importing a solution.